# How do i use the 'For each' statement?

Tags: vb.net, foreach

I'm working on a anti-virus and basically, when I scan my files, all the threats will be added to a list box and I'm trying to use a 'For each' statement to delete every item in the list box.

My code:

```
For Each threat As String In threatsLb.Items
    threatsLb.Select()
    Dim KillFile As String
    KillFile = threatsLb.SelectedItem.ToString()
    If Len(Dir$(KillFile)) > 0 Then
        SetAttr(KillFile, vbNormal)
        Kill(KillFile)
    End If
Next
```

Any suggestions why it isn't deleting the files from the items in the list box?

Comment: You have no code to remove any items from the Listbox. You need `threatsLb.RemoveAt` somewhere

Comment: @MattWilko - except that would be modifying the "collection" while iterating through it. Almost guaranteed to not be allowed or to produce unexpected results such as skipping items.

Comment: *I* know that - I was trying to lead the OP on a journey of enlightenment!

Answer (score 3):

The call to [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wt11hea(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't do what you think. It doesnt' make the current string selected and then you could grab it using SelectedItem. It just activates the ListBox control.

But you simply don't need it. The For Each statement loops over the items collection and gives back you an item at time to work with

So supposing that every item is a full path

```
For Each threat As String In threatsLb.Items
    File.SetAttributes(threat, FileAttributes.Normal)
    File.Delete(threat)
Next

' And finally 
threatsLb.Items.Clear()
```

Comment: Notice that I have removed all the _old-style_ VB6 calls. Try to use, when writing new code, the functions available in the NET Framework instead of the ones retained just for compatiblity with VB6/VBA